# XMLHttpRequest different response vs. jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've made three requests to the same URL which should return the same response- but guess what, they don't.

First, the working one is with jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/games?name=mkdd&callback=?",
  type: "GET",

  success: function(data){
    console.log("Succes with AJAX - ?", data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The second one is also with jQuery, but I changed the callback=? to callback=foo. I really can't figure out why this isn't working.

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/games?name=mkdd&callback=foo",
  type: "GET",

  success: function(data){
    console.log("Succes with AJAX - foo", data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Third one is just plain JavaScript - which I was planning on using. It's not working with whatever callback I'm using.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/games?name=mkdd&callback=?", true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    var resp = this.response;
    console.log("Succes with JS", resp);
  }
};

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send();
```

Can anybody help me with this problem? Am I missing something in my XMLHttpRequest? Why does the callback=? vs callback=foo matter so much?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bobtrol/2okpebvn/2/

Comment: You are making a `jsonp` request which is script request and does not use `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: That's it.. Thank you charlietfl.